# Electric field produced by ring of charge (opposite charge on each semi circle)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

The suggested solution in the following problem was written by the instructor at my University. I think there is an error and solved the problem my own way, but we can't seem to agree on the correct solution.
[image]
[image]
[image]
With λ being the charge density on the ring, which is Q/2piR or -Q/2piR depending on the semi circle.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let P be at the origin and the ring be in a plane perpendicular to the z axis, with its centre at (0, 0, *a*). Let the positive semicircle run from (*R*, 0, *a*) via (0, *R* *a*) to (–*R*, 0, *a*). Let angle $\phi$ be the angle between the radius running to a variable point on the ring, and the radius parallel to the *x*-axis. Then the displacement vector from the point to P is$$\vec{r}=-(a \vec{k}+R \cos \phi\ \vec{i} + R \sin \phi\ \vec{j})$$But the electric field at P due to the element of ring at angle $\phi$ is$$d\vec{E}=k_{E}\ \frac{Q\ d\phi}{2 \pi}\ \frac{\vec r}{r^3}\ \ \ \text{in which}\ \ \ r=(a^2+R^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

The field components at P in the *z* direction will cancel for the two halves of the ring. Neither half will have a resultant field component in the *x* direction (by symmetry), so we need only add the field components, $d\vec{E}.\vec{j}$, in the *y* direction. For the ring element at $\phi$, the contribution is$$dE_y=k_{E} \frac{Q}{2\pi r^3}d \phi\ \vec{r}.\vec{j}\ \ =\ -k_{E} \frac{Q}{2\pi r^3}d \phi\ R\sin \phi$$

So for the whole positive semicircle

$$E_y=-k_{E} \frac{QR}{2\pi r^3} \int_0 ^\pi \sin \phi\ d \phi\ \ =-\ \ k_{E} \frac{QR}{\pi r^3}.$$

For the negative semicircle$$E_y=-k_{E} \frac{-QR}{2\pi r^3} \int_\pi ^{2\pi} \sin \phi\ d \phi\ \ =-\ \ k_{E} \frac{QR}{\pi r^3}.$$

For both semicircles together, one half pulls in the *–y* direction and the other half pushes in that direction, so the total field strength will be twice as much.

I think that this answer is the same as yours, once you've re-expressed that pesky $\lambda$ !

Comment: Thank you for the very clear answer! Would you agree that the error in the suggested solution lies in the fact that the author did not take into consideration that he has to take the dot product of r and j, instead of assuming that the vector components that matter are already in the -y direction? Also yes, if I substitute lambda with Q/2pi R we indeed get the same result!

Comment: " the author did not take into consideration that he has to take the dot product of r and j, instead of assuming that the vector components that matter are already in the -y direction?" I think you're right. "yes, if I substitute lambda with Q/2pi R we indeed get the same result!" I knew that really; I just wanted to make a nasty remark about your $\lambda$, whose meaning I had to hunt for!